# (Seperable Variables) Can't Find Solution to First Order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to self study differential equations, but I've run into some confusion. My answer does not satisfy the original equation, but I cannot find the place where I made a mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

(Please excuse the picture instead of using MathJax, as I am not very familiar with it yet).

**Note:** Here are some equations in MathJax

$$x^1+2x=2c$$ where $c$ is some constant, $x=x(t)$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2c-2x$$
$$\int \frac{1}{2c-2x}dx=\int\mid dt$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{c-x}dx = \int\mid dt$$
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left[ -1n \mid c-x \mid\right]=t+c_1$$
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}[-\mid n \mid c - x \mid]} = e^{t+c_1}$$
$$e$$

Comment: on the left-hand side, towards the middle, you have separated the exponential where there was a product, not a sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from line six to seven in the picture, you have made the mistake 
$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln\vert c-x \vert}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{\ln\vert c-x \vert}$$
This should instead be 
$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln\vert c-x \vert}=\vert c-x \vert ^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$